# Graphing a scatterplot in Python to compare photometric and spectroscopic redshifts

Tags: python

I have a list of photometric redshifts and spectroscopic redshifts, and I need to make a scatterplot of these numbers to compare them. The problem is that I don't know how to make a scatterplot in python. How do you graph a scatterplot in python?

Answer (score 0):

Simple Approach

1. First import the matplotlib package
2. Use the plot method, then the scatter method (both contained within the matplotlib package) to create the scatterplot

---

```
import matplotlib

%matplotlib inline # to ensure the scatter output will be shown instead of code

your_data = pd.read_csv('your_dataset')

data = your_data # to avoid typing your_data each time

scatterplot = data.plot.scatter(x='select_your_x_axis', y='select_your_y_axis')

scatterplot.plot()
```

Hope this helps :)